# how to omit tns from response and change tag name in spyne?

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyne

how do omit tns from my response and also change the tag name.?
my response is like this

```
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="spyne.example">
  <soap11env:Body>
    <tns:FnSchedule_CityResponse>
      <tns:FnSchedule_CityResult>
        <tns:ErrorString></tns:ErrorString>
        <tns:CityName>HYDERABAD</tns:CityName>
        <tns:CityId>1</tns:CityId>
        <tns:ErrId>0</tns:ErrId>
      </tns:FnSchedule_CityResult>
    </tns:FnSchedule_CityResponse>
  </soap11env:Body>
</soap11env:Envelope>
```

I want to remove tns and change "soap11env" to "soap".
Having these values is causing validation issues.

i referred this question on stack overflow, implemented it, but was not helpful.
[Remove the namespace from Spyne response variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832969/remove-the-namespace-from-spyne-response-variables?lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change soap11env to soap just simply override the response using

```
application.interface.nsmap['soap'] = application.interface.nsmap['soap11env']
```

The 'tns' or target namespaces must not be change but there may arrive a few cases, One might need to change a name in order to completely test something.

To change the namespaces,

```
def on_method_return_string(ctx):
ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'ns4', b'diffgr')
ctx.out_string[0] = ctx.out_string[0].replace(b'ns5', b'msdata')
```

YourModelClassName.event_manager.add_listener('method_return_string',
                                              on_method_return_string)

What I did here was, replace the namespace ns4 with diffgr and ns5 with msdata. ns4 and ns5 are sub name spaces that I had in the responses of some third party application. This solution I found in the mailing list maintained for spyne.

Comment: please follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/31001419/1200441 to omit tns and soap11env